# How do I display the speed limit on Google Maps in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps

Is there a way to display the speed limit of an area in Google Maps on iOS?

I know speed limit overlays for Google Maps are possible on Android through third party apps, but I haven't been able to find an equivalent option for iOS.

Answer (score 5):

According to Google's [Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/odF5BOCvuNw;context-place=topicsearchin/maps/maps$20speed$20limit%7Csort:date), they're doing limited speed limit display tests in very specific areas.  I've seen San Francisco and Brazil being listed as the only places it's available right now.

They're also A/B testing in other locations.  No official release date has been given by Google for when this will be available on iOS.

To do a feature request:

1. Open Google Maps and make sure you’re signed in.
2. In the top left, click the Menu [image: menu button].
3. Tap 'Help & Feedback'.
4. Select 'Send Feedback'
5. Tap 'Send app feedback'
6. Click Send.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Google Maps.
2. Tap ☰.
3. Tap Settings.
4. Tap Navigation Settings.
5. Slide the Show Speed Limits switch right.

Comment: This does not work in Google Maps 4.51.8 on iOS 11.4. There is no option for “show speed limits”

Comment: Confirmed, same versions throughout but no option to show speed limit

Comment: Interesting, they must have removed this feature. It's a compromise, but I do know that Waze has speed limits and they are powered by the same servers as Google Maps (Google owns Waze). You could use that in the meantime until the speed limit functionality is restored for IOS.

Comment: @ThomasHood For completeness, that setting does not appear to be present on a current version of Google Maps for Android (9.79.2), either, so it's probably as fsb says.